# Alternative to passing a format string as keyword argument in Python 3.5+

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, python-3.5

In Python 3.5, using keyword arguments in `str.format` has been deprecated:

```
"Hi {s}".format(s="world")
```

From the [`string` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format):

> *Deprecated since version 3.5*: Passing a format string as keyword argument `format_string` has been deprecated.

What are the best alternatives in Python 3.5+?

Comment: Please fix the deprecation notice link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecation is about `string.Formatter` and not about `str.Formatter`:

[Source:](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/3.5.html#deprecated-python-modules-functions-and-methods)

> Passing a format string as keyword argument `format_string` to the `format()` method of the `string.Formatter` class has been deprecated.

You can use in `str.format`, but not in `string.Formatter`

Comment: Thanks for your clarification - I have misunderstood the deprecation warning. So I guess its fine to use `"Hi {s}".format(s="world")`  going forward?

Comment: @joshlk, yes, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `fstrings`:

```
name = "Bob"
hello = f"Hello {name}"
print (hello)
```

Output:

```
Hello Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
name = "john"
hello = "GoodMorning %s" %(name,)
print (hello)
```